# Difference between function and functor

Tags: c++, functor

I'm trying to write the following code:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    virtual int operator()()=0;
}
int bar()
{
    return 1;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    class : public MyClass{
        int operator()(){
            return 1;
        }
    } foo;
}
```

What's difference between `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: `bar` is a function. `foo` is an instance of a class with `operator()` defined.

Comment: I think that in this case we have instance `foo` of anonymous class and function `bar`. I think that it is two difference entity, is'n it?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes indeed, they're two very different things.

Comment: @St.Antario Correct. They are different.

Comment: What kind of _difference_ do you mean?

Comment: Apparently it's -1215877716 :) http://ideone.com/v2TGjW

Comment: What's the difference between a raven and a writing desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` is a function, but `foo` is a function object. So if (for example) you'll write something like:

```
std::for_each(myContainer.begin(), myContainer.end(), foo);
```

(see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each))
then your overloaded MyClass::operator() will be called for every single object in your container. The main advantage of function objects in comparison with function pointers is that they can be *nested*, it means that you can define your function class anywhere, including another classes or even methods. Moreover, it is ideal for usage in template functions, because `Function` can be template type.

Comment: You can also use free functions in StdLib algorithms; specifically you can replace `foo` with `bar` in your example. In C++11, local classes can also be used as template arguments.